# Exception occurs when script src is different, what's wrong with the code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

It works well when I use the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  //test for the marker
  var iconBase = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers/';
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: iconBase + 'markerA.png'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But an exception occured in the code below by changing the src js-file and I don't know why. The exception code was in the sentence "var marker = new google.mpas.LatLng". Can anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ditu.google.cn/maps?file=api&amp;v=3&amp;key=ABQIAAAAzr2EBOXUKnm_jVnk0OJI7xSosDVG8KKPE1-m51RBrvYughuyMxQ-i1QfUnH94QxWIa6N4U6MouMmBA&amp;hl=zh-CN"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  //test for the marker
  var iconBase = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers/';
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);    
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: iconBase + 'markerA.png'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have 2 protocols in the second src example (https and http). Remove the one you don't need.

Comment: One obvious problem is your use begins with https://http://

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, and I edited the question right now. The prolbem also exist. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the right solution, but it's not corresponding to "sensor" in the URL. The problem is that the url in second part of the question is incorrect. The url "ditu.google.cn/maps?file=api&v=2&key="; is correct for API version2, and it took no effect just by changing "v=2" to "v=3" and problem occured. The right url for v3 in China is "ditu.google.cn/maps/api/js?sensor=false";
Right code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Add markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ditu.google.cn/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=false"></script> 

    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  //test for the marker
  var iconBase = 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers/';
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: iconBase + 'markerA.png'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sensor` query string parameter is required by Google Maps API v3. It is present in the URL in your first example, but not in the second example.

Comment: Merry Christmas, and thanks for your answer. I have got the right solution, but it's not corresponding to "sensor" in the URL. The problem is that the url in second part of the question is incorrect. The url "http://ditu.google.cn/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=" is correct for API version2, and it took no effect just by changing "v=2" to "v=3" and problem occured. The right url for v3 in China is "http://ditu.google.cn/maps/api/js?sensor=false".

Comment: @user_Onlinar, glad you figured it out. You should probably write that as an answer and accept it...